# Why does memset for sizeof a VLA work differently on different C++ versions?

Tags: g++

I am trying to use memset in my C++ code. However the code works unexpectedly on my machine.

OS :- MacOS 10.12

G++ :- g++-4.9 (Homebrew GCC 4.9.4_1) 4.9.4

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int test;
    cin >> test;
    while(test--){
        int size = 1e5+10;
        int arr[size];
        memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr));
        int cnt = 0;
        for(ll i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if(arr[i]==0) cnt++;
        }
        cout << cnt << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Command 1 :-**

`g++ -std=c++14 file.cpp` and then `./a.out`

I get the output

`96835`

with the warning

```
file.cpp: In function 'int main()':
file.cpp:17:32: warning: taking sizeof array of runtime bound [-Wvla]
         memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr));
```

**Command 2 :-**

`g++ -std=c++11 file.cpp` and then `./a.out`

I get the output

`100010`

As you can see 2 is correct and 1 is incorrect. What can be the reason for such unexpected behavior?

Comment: Listen to your warnings.  `VLA`'s are not standard and should not be used.  If you need a run time sized array use `std::vector`.

Comment: And don't include `bits/c++.h`.

Comment: Okay. But I tried running the same code on an online compiler and got the correct result. Are they passing some additional flags? @NathanOliver

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher You are right. But I use this template only for competitive coding purposes.

Comment: Seeing as you’re using a g++-specific language extension, have you studied its documentation and determined that they *should* give the same  (and expected) result?

Comment: When you use something that isn't guaranteed by the standard you get un-guaranteed resilts

Comment: @NathanOliver Adding const to my size variable fixed it. This is a more correct way of doing things right? Because now it's not a run time bound.

Comment: Since `c++11` there is std::array<> for fixed sized arrays. That would be a better choice in modern code.

Comment: @HarshKhajuria If the array size is known at compile time you can just hard code it into the brackets or make it a global const variable.

Comment: @HarshKhajuria: So, what did you investigatin reveal: what is the reason for the "inocorrect " output? Did you end up with `size = 96835` in the first version of code? Or end up with `size = 100010`, but `memset` not setting everything to `0`? What exactly failed in the first version?

Answer (score 5):

Your program is ill-formed. The size of an array must be compile time constant, you use a non-constant variable.

You're using GCC which allows Variable Length Arrays as a language extension to C++. The feature is similar to Variable Length Arrays which are standard in C99, although as AnT points out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54096411/why-does-memset-for-sizeof-a-vla-work-differently-on-different-c-versions#comment95026875_54096644), the C++ extension differs from the standard C VLA.

However, there used to be a proposal to add "Runtime-sized arrays with automatic storage duration" to the C++ standard. The proposal differs from GCC's extension in that `sizeof` of a runtime sized array is ill-formed (differences are not necessarily limited to this). GCC 4.9 implemented this proposal in the experimental C++14 mode before the proposal was withdrawn from the standard draft.

So, your program is ill-formed in all official C++ standard versions which don't have VLA, but well-formed in GNU extended C++ which has VLA, but ill-formed again in the experimental standard implemented by GCC 4.9 which has runtime-sized arrays but no `sizeof` for them.

Since the size of the array is constant, you can make your program well-formed simply by declaring the variable constant as well:

```
const int size = 1e5+10;
```

Now, no run time sized array is used.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because VLA (Variable Length Arrays) are not supported in C++. Some compilers support them anyway, sort of, because they already have the code for C99.

But since it isn't defined for C++, what you get is kind of random. For example, `sizeof` may not be a function call in C++. In C99, it is for VLAs. But in C++ it might not be. Which means it would return a fixed number, that may not be exactly what you expect.

Comment: Okay. What if I use `const int size = 1e5+10` instead? Will that be a correct way of doing things?

Comment: C++ compilers do not "support" VLA. Some C++ compilers allow specifying run-time values as array sizes, but the resultant arrays behave very very very differently from C VLA. They behave *fundamentally* differently. C VLA are critically incompatible with C++ and cannot be implemented in C++ even as an extension. No C++ compiler supports VLA. Whatever looks like "VLA" in C++ has only a superficial resemblance.

Comment: @AnT GCC docs say *"Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++"*. So, they seem to call it VLA. How do C++ "not-VLA" differ from C VLA? I know there are problems combining C++ features with them, but is there any difference in "not-VLA" of POD objects compared to identically declared VLA in C?

Comment: @eerorika: This is a misleading oversimplification. GCC docs are lying. GCC does not support C VLA in C++ code. For starters, in C an innocent VLA-typedef is a code-generating declaration (!): it has to memorize the size of the array at the moment of `typedef` (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d9302ef4ca9d11b). In C++ code-generating `typedef` is completely unacceptable, which results in fundamentally different behavior: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d606c9a69772b218 . See the difference? And this is purely POD.

Comment: In C you are prohibited from jumping over a VLA-typedef (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67ab114137574e92) for the very same reason - it generates critically important code. In C++ the idea of "prohibiting to jump over a mere typedef" does not really fit into the current design of the language. There's no way the C concept of "variably modified type" can be carried over to C++ without demolishing a major part of C++ language specification.

Comment: When GCC says that they are supporting VLA in C++ code "as an extension" this is either oversimplification or incompetence. (Hopefully, the former.) No, they are not supporting anything even remotely resembling VLA in C++ code. They are merely allowing to specify array size by a runtime value. And this is where the similarity ends. The rest of their C++ behavior is very different from C VLA even if we restrict consideration to POD data.

Comment: GCC should start slowly removing the abomination of VLA in C++ by turning them off by default instead of turning them on.  What often winds up happening is what you're seeing now - new programmers believe they're writing valid C++ code when they're not.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie At the very least they should show a diagnostic by default (without having to set `-pedantic`). After all, standard requires it.